# Error while refitting ARIMA model

Tags: r, xts, zoo, arima

I am getting the following error when I try to refit the ARIMA model.

```
new_model <- Arima(data,model=old_model)
Error in Ops.Date(driftmod$coeff[2], time(x)) : 
  * not defined for "Date" objects
```

Note: The class of data is `zoo`. I also tried using `xts`, but I got the same error.

Edit: As suggested by Joshua, here is the reproducible example.

```
library('zoo')
library('forecast')

#Creating sample data
sample_range <- seq(from=1, to=10, by=1)
x<-sample(sample_range, size=61, replace=TRUE)
ts<-seq.Date(as.Date('2017-03-01'),as.Date('2017-04-30'), by='day')
dt<-data.frame(ts=ts,data=x)

#Split the data to training set and testing set
noOfRows<-NROW(dt)
trainDataLength=floor(noOfRows*0.70)
trainData<-dt[1:trainDataLength,]
testData<-dt[(trainDataLength+1):noOfRows,]

# Use zoo, so that we get dates as index of dataframe
trainData.zoo<-zoo(trainData[,2:ncol(trainData)], order.by=as.Date((trainData$ts), format='%Y-%m-%d'))
testData.zoo<-zoo(testData[,2:ncol(testData)], order.by=as.Date((testData$ts), format='%Y-%m-%d'))

#Create Arima Model Using Forecast package 
old_model<-Arima(trainData.zoo,order=c(2,1,2),include.drift=TRUE)

# Refit the old model with testData
new_model<-Arima(testData.zoo,model=old_model)
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/271616), including `library()` calls to the packages you're using?

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Sorry for the delay. I just posted a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `?Arima` page says that `y` (the first argument) should be a `ts` object.  My guess is that the first call to `Arima` coerces your `zoo` object to `ts`, but the second call does not.

An easy way to work-around this is to explicitly coerce to `ts`:

```
# Refit the old model with testData
new_model <- Arima(as.ts(testData.zoo), model = old_model)
```

Comment: Wow, this worked like a charm. Thanks :)
I had tried out my code when include.drift=FALSE, and it worked perfectly, any idea why this error occurs when drift is set to TRUE?

Comment: @ganapathy: no idea... perhaps a bug?